# How to change or update name, email and phone number in contact module by using Account relational field in suitCRM or sugarCRM?

Tags: crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

In contact module I've add an relational field of account. Now I want that when I use the account field and select an account from the list, then the name , email , and phone number field of contact module will fill out with the name , email and phone of that account which will I select by using relational field of account.
How can I do that please define the code and also directory where I have to add your define code to perfome this task.

I've tried a logic hook by searching over the internet, in my directory of custom/module/contacts/populated fields.php, here is the code but it didn't working at all.

```
`<?php
if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) {
    die('Not a valid entry point.');
}
class PopulateFields
{
    function populate($bean, $event, $arguments)
    {
        // Check if the Account field has changed
        if ($bean->account_id != $bean->fetched_row['account_id']) {
            // Retrieve the selected Account's information
            $accountBean = BeanFactory::getBean('Accounts', $bean->account_id)     
            // Populate the fields with the Account's information
            if (!empty($accountBean)) {
                $bean->name = $accountBean->name;
                $bean->email1 = $accountBean->email1;
              $bean->phone_office = $accountBean->phone_mobile;
            }
        }
    }
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill out those information on Record View itself then you might need to write the custom logic at the front end (record.js)

Check Sugar Cookbook - https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_12.0/Cookbook

And, If you're okay that it should populate after you click on the save button on record view then (before_save) Logic hook would be the best approach.

https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_13.0/Architecture/Logic_Hooks/Module_Hooks/before_save/

Hope it helps!